# Измерение времени выполнения программы в наносекундах

Tags: c++, время, производительность

Как измерить время выполнения программы в наносекундах?

Answer (score 5):

Сколь-нибудь точно - никак.

Конечно, если программа длинная, то ко времени в секундах можно дописать девять нулей :)

Для хоть какой-то надежности требуется многократное выполнение с делением на количество повторов, да еще и с усреднением по нескольким запускам.

Ну, а в качестве таймера - я, например, для себя набросал такой, чтоб попроще в использовании -

```
class muTimer
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    bool active = false;
    Clock::duration   duration_;
    Clock::time_point start_ = Clock::now(), stop_ = Clock::now();

    muTimer(const muTimer&)             = delete;
    muTimer& operator=(const muTimer&)  = delete;
public:
    using ns       = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using mks      = std::chrono::microseconds;
    using ms       = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    muTimer() { reset(); start(); }
    ~muTimer() = default;
    muTimer& reset()
    {
        duration_ = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
        active    = false;
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& start()
    {
        if (!active)
        {
            start_ = Clock::now();
            active = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& stop()
    {
        if (active)
        {
            stop_      = Clock::now();
            duration_ += stop_ - start_;
            active     = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename T = mks>
        unsigned long long duration()
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned long long>
            (std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(stop_-start_).count());
    }
};
```

Тогда достаточно написать

```
{
    muTimer mt;

    // Исследуемый код

    cout << mt.stop().duration() << " mks\n";

    // Или, скажем,
    cout << mt.stop().duration<muTimer::ms>() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: классно!  Но у меня к вам один вопрос по поводу деструктора. Я не знал о таком присваивании. Не разьясните?...

Comment: Да просто деструктор пусть генерирует компилятор, у меня там ничего специфичного нет, чтоб свой писать...

Answer (score 2):

дРаспространенные процессоры имеютв архитектруре непривилегированную команду, которая возвращает количество тиков, прошедших с какого-то момента времени. Эта команда обычно завернута в соответствующую функцию системной библиотеки, которая в том или ином виде появляется в языках программирования. Что касается c/с++, то получить время, которое затратила программа на выполнение участка кода, позволяет функция clock() из стандартной библиотеки c++ (ISO/IEC 14882:2011 7.27.2.1 The clock function). Пример кода:

```
#include <cstdio>    // printf()
#include <ctime>     // clock_t, clock(), CLOCKS_PER_SEC
void do_something(); // Ее мы желаем "взвесить" на весах времени

int main () {

  clock_t t;

  t = clock();
  do_something();
  t = clock() - t;

  printf ("do_something() time : %ld clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Наверное, `(%lf seconds)` - раз `double`?